# How to use parameters inside a block when defining an extension function?

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

```
val test: Int.(String) -> Int = {
  plus((this))
}
```

When defining this type of `extension function`, how can I use `arguments( Here, the argument of type String)` inside the block?

When defining `extension functions` at the same time as declaration like this, can only `this` be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it using `it`:

```kotlin
val test: Int.(String) -> Int = {
  println("this = $this")
  println("it = $it")
  42
}

fun main() {
    println("result = " + 1.test("a"))
}
```

This will output

```
this = 1
it = a
result = 42
```

An alternative is to introduce a lambda-parameter:

```kotlin
val test: Int.(String) -> Int = { s ->
  println("this = $this")
  println("s = $s")
  42
}

fun main() {
    println("result = " + 1.test("a"))
}
```

This will output

```
this = 1
s = a
result = 42
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.
I thought the argument `s` replaced `this`. I understand well thanks to you.